# Find match that satisfies multiple conditions in Excel

Tags: indexing, excel-formula, match, multiple-conditions

Imagine I have the following set of data:

```
h   |   t   |   ID
60  |   6   |   HP60x6
80  |   5   |   HP80x5
80  |   6   |   HP80x6
80  |   7   |   HP80x7
100 |   6   |   HP100x6
100 |   7   |   HP100x7
```

Now, let's say I want to get the ID for an element with h=80 and t=6. Since the is an exact match (ID=HP80x6), I solved it using this:

```
{=INDEX(C1:C6;MATCH(1;(80=A1:A6)*(6=B1:B6);0))}
```

My problem is if I want to find something like h=70 and t=6. As there is no exact match, I want to guarantee that the ID that I get back is the minimum that guarantees h>=70 and t>=6. In other words, e.g., although ID=HP80x7 respects the condition of h>=70 and t>=6, it is not the ID with the minimum values. In this case I would expect obtaining ID=HP80x6 (same as the previous case). How could I solve this in a single cell, without adding more columns or rows for intermediate calculations?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just change the `=` in the MATCH to `>=`

Comment: as mentioned by Scott, try `INDEX(C1:C6,MATCH(1,(Value_h<=A1:A6)*(Value_t<=B1:B6),0))` confirmed by pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter